# using just session how do set my submit button color red even when page refresh

Tags: php, forms, session, colors, submit

am new to php but in acchievement i want to set by submit form button color red for long time  even when page reload this my tried code

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
   {

   $_SESSION["form_post"] = "Yes";

   }

   if(isset($_SESSION["form_post"]) && $_SESSION["form_post"] =="Yes") 

   {

   echo yes;

   }


   echo '<style type="text/css">


     .buttn-on-post {

   color: red;

     }
```

Your Phone Number

```
   <input type="submit" class="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["form_post"])) { echo "buttn-on-post"; }  
   ?>';
```

every thing work fine but my submit button color do not change please can any one fixed this? Big thanks in advance

Comment: Please make sure that you did not make mistakes while copying your code to the question, because, there is a problem with the quotes (**"** and **'** )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store a variable in the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) superglobal variable as this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// default color
if(!isset( $_SESSION['submitColor']))  $_SESSION['submitColor'] = 'black';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    $_SESSION["form_post"] = "Yes";

    // set the color as red in the session
    $_SESSION['submitColor'] = 'red'; 
}

if(isset($_SESSION["form_post"]) && $_SESSION["form_post"] =="Yes") 
{
    echo yes;
}
echo "<style type=\"text/css\">
.buttn-on-post {
    background-color: {$_SESSION['submitColor']};
}
</style>";
?>

<form method='post'>
<input type="submit" class="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["form_post"])) { echo "buttn-on-post"; }?>">
</form>
```

**Note:** at the first opening of your web page, there isn't the `$_SESSION["form_post"]` variable, it'll be set after the first user's post action.

Comment: i love your method but i get this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file,
expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
or
${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES)
or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) 

this is the line for the error 
<inp
ut type="submit" class="<?php if(isset($_SESSION["form_post"])) { echo "buttn-on-post"; }">
   
please can you kindly fixed it?

Comment: does this code works? `<input type="submit" class="buttn-on-post">`

Comment: See my last edit. (`background-color: {$_SESSION[submitColor]};
`). The code raise an error? Which part does not work?

Comment: yes but can kindly put this on your webserver to see it your self? This isn't working am with your current code the problem is that the session color do not inset into record as am expected to see (yes) an a submit button but i get just the submit button even on click big thanks for your time and impact in my soluction

Comment: try now, must be inserted also the `<form>` if it still there isn't in your code and then check some corrections. On my web-server it works after clicking on the submit.

Answer (score 1):

### **Try below example:** Set button color in [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

```
<?php 
session_start(); // start session 
$_SESSION['color'] = "";
/* Condition for check button is clicked */
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['color'] = "red";
}
?>
<!-- HTML Form -->
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" style="background-color:
<?php echo $_SESSION['color']; ?>">
</form>
```